# macOS Server: How to make mail server use TLS/SSL

Tags: osx-server, ssl, smtp

I've set up the Mail component in the Server.app to provide an internal mail server. We used to use this mail server to send mail (via SMTP) without TLS on port 25 which worked well enough.

Now I wanted to secure SMTP with either SSL/TLS , but I cannot get it to work. This is what I did:

- In the Server.app, under *Certificates*, I've assigned an SSL certificate to the service *Mail (SMTP)* as well as to *Mail (IMAP and POP)*
- I've tried to send mail via SMTP with SSL on ports 25, 587, and 465, which all failed.
- I've tried to send mail via SMTP with StartTLS on the same port, which succeeded on port 25 and 587.
- I've tried to send mail without any secure channel, which succeeded on port 25 and 587.

My conclusions are

- port 465 is not available
- ports 25 and 587 respond identically
- StartTLS works, and it's using the configured certificate
- SSL does not work

Trying to verify SSL with openssl gives me the following error

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect smtp.mail.localdomain:25 -servername smtp.mail.localdomain 
CONNECTED(00000005)
4306470444:error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/a0876c02-1788-11ed-b9c4-96898e02b808/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:386:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Start Time: 1663316761
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Verifying StartTLS with openssl shows that it indeed works.

Why does connecting over SSL/TLS not work? What am I missing here?

Comment: I get the same error when trying to establish a connection to a gRpc server.  Using a different ssl, the error message is 
"io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 000006040000000000000500004000"

And wireshark shows an (extra) "Continuation Data" packet containing those bytes as the payload. My best guess is that this is negotiation for Server Name Indication that is not supported on the client side.